Store data files in Persistent Volume in Openshift ROSA
I have an API that accesses some data files ( size around 12 MB altogether) during its runtime. I am deploying this API into OpenShift ROSA. I need to store these files somewhere in a persistent storage in ROSA so that the API can access them whenever required - the API does not modify these files, just uses them to do some operations.So I only need to store them once and they will be read many times. But all the pods need to be able to access these files while they are up and running.
I was thinking of creating a persistent volume from the Openshift Console and then use the below command during the pipeline run to set the volumes.
sh "$oc set volume deployment/${generateEnvAppName()} --add --name=${appConfig.persistentVolumeClaimName} --claim-name=${appConfig.persistentVolumeClaimName} --type pvc --mount-path=/config"

My deployment.yaml file is as below:


apiVersion: template.openshift.io/v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: "${APP_NAME}-deployment"
objects:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "${APP_NAME}-${APP_REGION}"
      name: "${APP_NAME}-${APP_REGION}"
      namespace: ${APP_NAMESPACE}
    spec:
      replicas: ${{REPLICA_COUNT}}
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          deployment: "${APP_NAME}-${APP_REGION}"
      strategy:
        rollingUpdate:
          maxSurge: 25%
          maxUnavailable: 25%
        type: RollingUpdate
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: ${APP_NAME}
            deployment: "${APP_NAME}-${APP_REGION}"
          annotations:
            deploy_date: ${DEPLOY_DATE}
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
              - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
                value: ${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}
              - name: TZ
                value: ""
              - name: BUILD_DATE
                value: ${BUILD_DATE}
              image: "${REGISTRY_PREFIX}/${APP_NAME}:${IMAGE_VERSION}"
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: ${APP_NAME}
              livenessProbe:
                failureThreshold: 3
                httpGet:
                  path: ${LIVENESS_CHECK_URL}
                  port: 8080
                  scheme: HTTP
                initialDelaySeconds: ${{HEALTH_CHECK_DELAY}}
                periodSeconds: 10
                successThreshold: 1
                timeoutSeconds: 10
              readinessProbe:
                failureThreshold: 3
                httpGet:
                  path: ${READINESS_CHECK_URL}
                  port: 8080
                  scheme: HTTP
                initialDelaySeconds: ${{HEALTH_CHECK_DELAY}}
                periodSeconds: 10
                successThreshold: 1
                timeoutSeconds: 10
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 500m
                  memory: 4Gi
                requests:
                  cpu: 50m
                  memory: 256Mi
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              volumeMounts:
                - name: "${APP_NAME}-config-${APP_REGION}"
                  mountPath: /opt/app-root/config
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          restartPolicy: Always
          volumes:
            - name: "${APP_NAME}-config-${APP_REGION}"
              configMap:
                defaultMode: 420
                name: "${APP_NAME}-config-${APP_REGION}"
      test: false
      triggers:
        - type: ConfigChange
parameters:
  - name: APP_NAME
    description: "Application name."
    



I created the persistent volume, it shows as 'Bound' , but when I run the deploy steps ( it sets the volume at this stage), the pods are not able to start because it is expecting the data files to be present in the /config location. The pods crash because of this. I was hoping to use the "oc rsh"  command to copy the files form local machine to the persistent volume, but I have no idea what will be the destination.
Could anyone tell me if my thinking is right? If yes, where will I copy the files to

Are the data files the same or different for all your environments (testing vs staging vs production)? If they are all the same regardless of which environments, it would be better to embed the data files into custom docker images of your application.

@Lukman - they are the same in all environments. Did you mean to include them in the packaged jar file?

In your container image file

@Lukman - could you give me an example of how to do that please
